# Mapping values over a curve

Tags: algorithms, game-development

I have a value between 0 and 8000 and I want this number to resolve to another number between 0 and 2000. I could just divide it by 4 but I have a special need here.

For values above 4000 I want the mapped value to be biased towards the 2000. But for values lower than 4000 I want the mapped value to be biased towards 0.

This is actually for a game where you are given bonus points between 0 and 2000 depending on how quickly you complete the task. So if you are very fast and do it in 7500 milliseconds you should get 1875 points (exactly 7500 / 4). If you do it in 6000 milliseconds you would get 1450 points (a little under 6000 / 4). If you are slow and do it in 1000 milliseconds you would get 50 milliseconds (well under 1000 / 4). The idea is to reward fast players more than slow players but still let slow players feel like they've achieved something. I feel an "eased-out" value mapping would achieve this.

I hope this makes sense. Can you help me figure out some code that achieves this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function):

[image]

It will map values from `-(range/2) to +(range/2)` to a scale between 0.0 and 1.0, with the midpoint at 0 *). The nice thing is that changing the `range` yields different curves. Here's an example with values from 1-2000 mapped on using the sigmoid:

[image: sigmoid on the rating range 1 - 2000]

Here are [two runs](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/gist.github.com/miraculixx/24c11a60550dcc009f44/raw/c748da6cff1adca420481ce255923cac0fb8a179/rating.ipynb?create=1) of the function using different values of the range (r):

```
  ms     r=6    r=20
    0      94       0
  500     135       0
 1000     190       1
 1500     265       3
 2000     364      13
 2500     490      45
 3000     641     151
 3500     814     445
 4000    1000    1000
 4500    1186    1555
 5000    1359    1849
 5500    1510    1955
 6000    1636    1987
 6500    1735    1997
 7000    1810    1999
 7500    1865    2000
 8000    1906    2000
```

*) actually, it maps between -infinity to +infinity, but for your purpose selecting a range between -10/+10 up to -30/+30 should work.

Comment: Perfect. Great answer. I got this working in C# http://dotnetfiddle.net/wzLYUn. Now I need to port it over to Objective C for the game.